# Comparing String concatenation

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I was wondering what the best way is to concat two strings.
Coming from a C# background I am used to `String.Format(...)`,`StringBuilder` and of course `+`.

In Axapta (4.0) I have now seen:

```
str str1, str2, str3;
;

str1 = 'Hello';
str2 = 'world';

str3 = strfmt('%1 %2',str1,str2);
info(str3);

str3 = str1+' '+str2;
info(str3);
```

My question would be, what is concidered best practise and why ?
And to make it **not** opinion based: Is there a speed difference ?

Comment: I'm not an Axapta expert, but imho the concatenation is always the fastest one, because there are no cast involved of the function strfmt. Best practice is a bit subjective, for example for me a best practice is a readable code and in this case I will prefer strfmt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple + operator is fastest as you can quickly benchmark yourself with some loop and a high number of iterations. See below for a quick example which takes (on my machine) ~ 7 secs for the + operator and ~ 10 secs for `strfmt`. As already pointed out by [Guido Preite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2191473/guido-preite), write it for the best readability but usually in AX `strfmt` is used for building up strings facing the user (e.g. through the infolog).

```
static void StrConcatPerf(Args _args)
{
    int i;
    int startTime;
    int endTime;

    str concat2StringsWithOperator(str _lhs, str _rhs)
    {
        ;

        return _lhs + _rhs;
    }

    str concat2StringsWithStrFmt(str _lhs, str _rhs)
    {
        ;

        return strfmt('%1%2', _lhs, _rhs);
    }
    ;


    startTime = timenow();
    for (i = 0; i < 2000000; ++i)
    {
        //concat2StringsWithStrFmt('lhs_string', 'rhs_string');
        //concat2StringsWithOperator('lhs_string', 'rhs_string');
    }
    endTime = timenow();

    info(strfmt("Processing time was %1 secs", endTime - startTime));
}
```